# Log new files in a directory

Tags: files, utilities

Is there a tool, which lets me know about the last newly created files?

The still common way of using a hierarchically file system makes it hard to save files in different places, so sometimes I sort things into general topic folders and sometimes at the place of directly related things, f.e. publications related to a certain tool in the directory of the binaries.

Best would be a tool, which I can ask:

- Period of creation / saving
- File type / name / extension
- Black-/Whitelist of directories to exclude/include

Comment: which operating systems are you interested in?

Comment: pqnet: Debian GNU/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command line tools supporting such actions is `find`:

### Examples

```
find /path -iname '*.ext' # search for extension (don't forget the quotes)
find /path -mtime n       # search for last modified `n*24h` ago
find /path -atime n       # search for last accessed `n*24h` ago
find /path -newer ref     # newer than ref
find /path -size +100M    # larger than 100MB
find /path -perm 664      # example to search for files with a specific permission
find /path -type <t>      # search for file `f`, directory `d`, symbolic link `l` ...
```

In order to ask for more details on the filetype, I suggest running something along the lines of

```
find /path -type f -exec file '{}' \; | grep 'Vorbis audio'
```

I'm not aware of a tool (particularly a GUI tool) which is as capable as `find`.

Comment: Combining your serious answer with bantering humor would look nearly the same. So I'll grin every time I'll use 'find' for this task :)

Comment: Why does `find -atime` give my always a different result (fewer entries) on the 2nd run, short after the 1st run?

Comment: good question, I have not experienced this before. You should ask a new question! Please provide the exact commands you're using.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `inotify` if you need to know immediately

If you need to know about the newly created files immediately, you can actually wait for the event of creating a file in a directory, or in a directory tree, using the `inotify` API on linux (see `man 7 inotify`):

You would combine this with parts of the other solutions to find out the detailed information about the files.

### Example watching file creation

Below, the command `inotifywait -e create -m /path` is started. When it waits after the line `Watches established.`, a new file `foo` is created in `/path` on another terminal:

```
term1$ inotifywait -e create -m /path
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

```
term2$ touch /path/foo
```

```
term1$ inotifywait -e create -m /path
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
./ CREATE foo
^C
```

(first 3 lines repeated from above)

Without the `-m` (`--monitor`) option `inotifywait` stops after the first event, which can be useful in a script loop.